# Caching Go Depencencies in Docker

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile, go-modules, docker-buildkit

I've read [articles](https://www.docker.com/blog/containerize-your-go-developer-environment-part-2/) in which it is advised to have a dedicated `go mod download` layer for downloading go dependencies. I understand that the layer is cached and if the dependencies don't change in the next build, the cached layer will be used, saving us time.
I've also noticed that using BuildKit mounting feature, the `go build` binary results are cached in `GO env GOCACHE` directory, in order to be used for future builds.

Now the thing is a lot of the time only a few of the go dependencies are changed, therefore the cached `go mod download` layer is invalidated. And as a result, in the next build, all the dependencies will be downloaded again, even if only a few of them have changed.
My question is if is ok to mount the downloaded packages (dependencies)? And what would be the downsides of doing that? I haven't seen this technique to be used in Go Dockerfile best practices.
Something like

```
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/go/pkg/mod go mod download
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can just start doing that and see. For me, if I had to use this, I would choose a different mount path, just to isolate the local environment.

```
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/Users/me/Library/Caches go mod download
```

I don't see any problem mounting downloaded packages. In this [example](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/syntax.md#example-cache-apt-packages), it is used for `apt`.

However, I think we can also take a step back and consider different approaches to not to be bothered by waiting for Docker build.

We can have scheduled builds (nightly build and etc), I don't see any reason to do local docker build that frequent, especially your dependencies shouldn't change that often. Maybe I am wrong, but I don't think we need to.

We can also further break down `go mod download` and leverage Docker build cache
E.g.

```
RUN go mod download package-never-change
RUN go mod download package-changes-frequently
```

Even

```
RUN go build ./package1
RUN go build ./package2
```

It maybe look a little bit tedious, but under certain circumstances it could be useful, for example, when BuildKit is not supported.